# How to query a pair like table structure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Before Query

```
User   Friend

A      B
A      C
D      A
F      A
```

After Query

```
User   Friend

A      B
A      C
A      D
A      F
```

How can I get the result shown. I want to get all friends of A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a union:

```
select user, friend 
from t
where user = 'A'
union 
select friend, user
from t
where friend = 'A'
```

Notice than `Union` behavior is `distinct` that is that you expect ( opposed to `union all` )

Comment: +1 for understanding .. i really dont know how u have understand it ... but i was not able to do it .

Comment: @Dhaval, thanks. It is not the first time I get a comment like yours. Thanks you about to realize it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  USER AS 'User',
        friend AS 'Friend'
FROM    t
WHERE   USER = 'A'
UNION
SELECT  friend ,
        USER
FROM    t
WHERE   friend = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a UNION

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [User]='A' THEN [user] ELSE [friend] END as [A], CASE WHEN [User]='A' THEN [friend] ELSE [user] END AS [Friend Of A] WHERE [user]='A' OR [friend]='A'
```